# C# and Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have multiple files, from which I have to extract tables containing data. Problem is tables don't have IDs, so I have to search based on the  content (which is constant in each file). There are multiple tables in each file and the table of interest doesn't have constant XPath.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" bordercolor="#111111">
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td class="s">CONSTANT_TEXT</td>
            <td class="l">CHANGING_VALUE</td>
        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <td class="s"> </td>
            <td class="l"><a style="" id="CONSTANT_ID" href="mailto: XXXX</a>
 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

How do I:
1. Search based on the CONSTANT_TEXT  CONSTANT_TEXT , return the value of 2nd TD  CHANGING_VALUE , without knowing the  Path (it doesn't have ID and it's position changes from file to file).
2. Search based on CONSTANT_TEXT  CONSTANT_TEXT , return the Parent table of that TD

What I did is to search and return  CONSTANT_TEXT , with Html Agility Pack, then iterate the XPath upwards until the Table is reached.

```
var output= document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='CONSTANT_ID']");
output[0].XPath ="/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/thead[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/a[1]"
```

My plan was to iterate each output and get the XPath for lowest table occurring, table[1], then extract the data.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You could simply iterate over all the tables on the page and then select again the nodes inside the table node to check if your special string is present. It's generally easier to navigate down the HTML tree than up using HtmlAgility Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you'll need the following XPath :

> Search based on the CONSTANT_TEXT CONSTANT_TEXT , return the value of
>   2nd TD CHANGING_VALUE

```
//td[.="CONSTANT_TEXT"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```

Output : `CHANGING_VALUE`

> Search based on CONSTANT_TEXT CONSTANT_TEXT , return the Parent table of that TD

```
//td[.="CONSTANT_TEXT"]/ancestor::table[1]
```

Output : `<table> element`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the example, I've got the full table returned correctly.
Note that I can't iterate through tables, I have over 1k files to process with multiple tables in them.

Comment: Hello,
How about searching for two variables,  CONSTANT_TEXT in TD  and TD class="s"  and returning the table?

`<TD class="s">CONSTANT_TEXT</TD> `

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use `and` operator. So it will be :  `//td[.="CONSTANT_TEXT" and @class="s"]/ancestor::table[1]`

Comment: Too easy, Thank you!